# Fastest way to create a copy of snowflake database

Tags: sql, deployment, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to make a copy of the database to check my code before release in snowflake.

Currently, we use clone method for creating copy of database: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

But it's take around 15 min. I'm trying to find faster way to create a copy (with or without copying data - it doesn't matter).

What I tried:

- get_ddl function for whole database - returns objects without saving order of creating creating objects

Maybe someone know better options for it?

Comment: You must have a lot of objects in your database - zero copy clone is a metadata only operation (no data is actually copied), and performance is typically very fast.   Out of curiosity, how many db objects are we talking here?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue with using SELECT GET_DDL('DATABASE', 'MY_DATABASE_NAME')?  You mention it doesn't save the order of creating the objects - in my experience the result set includes the DDL in proper dependency order.

Comment: @JimDemitriou - Not really, I also encountered this problem, GET_DDL does not return in the right order, e.g. when you have several layers of nested views, unfortunately it is not very useful.

Comment: @jim-demitriou, we have around 1200 objects in our database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone several schemas in parallel at the same time.

Write a stored procedure that will create a root TASK and sub tasks for each schema you will clone in the database. Then you run root TASK.

Sample code.

At the beginning, the 'TASK root' which creates the database:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK root_clone_task
WAREHOUSE = 'COMPUTE_WH'
AS
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE CLONE_MY_DB;
```

Then as many sub-tasks as you have schema to clone, or preferably 8 sub-tasks and balanced cloning between them (by default WH supports 8 threads in parallel):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK sub_clone_task1
WAREHOUSE = 'COMPUTE_WH'
AFTER root_clone_task
AS
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA CLONE_MY_DB.SCHEMA1 CLONE MY_DB.SCHEMA1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK sub_clone_task2
WAREHOUSE = 'COMPUTE_WH'
AFTER root_clone_task
AS
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA CLONE_MY_DB.SCHEMA2 CLONE MY_DB.SCHEMA2;
```

Then we need to resume all the sub-tasks, this can be done one at a time using `ALTER TASK <name> RESUME` or we can use the command:

```sql
select system$task_dependents_enable('MY_DB.PUBLIC.root_clone_task');
```

You will get the error message:

> "Task should have a SCHEDULE or AFTER to be resumed."

If you want to avoid this you can define SCHEDULE in root TASK, but all child tasks will be enabled.

Finally, just execute the root TASK:

```sql
EXECUTE TASK root_clone_task;
```

Of course, you can automate this by writing a stored procedure with dynamic code that will generate all the necessary tasks.

At the end, it seems to me that it takes most of the time to move metadata and information about permissions, and in many cases we remove these permissions later to give them a completely different one.
Therefore, I proposed a new idea: `Add an option WITHOUT PRIVILEGES to the CLONE option`.

Please go to the website: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas
and search for the idea:

`Add an option WITHOUT PRIVILEGES to the CLONE option`
and vote for it, I hope it will significantly speed up the cloning process.

Comment: Interesting - this would imply that the cloning of a database processes the underlying objects serially.  The stored proc you're recommending would first create a database, and then create a root task used to kick off multiple parallel executions of schema clones from the source DB to the new one.  Is there any reference to this approach and the expected performance gains?  It seems if this accelerates the cloning, that it would be in the interest of the Snowflake team to build this into the cloning DB process.

Comment: @Jim Demetriou - thank you for your interest, in our case the cloning lasted 1h 15min, after SF optimization it shortened to 35min, after parallelization of cloning on the schema level, we went down to 15min. Important thing: by default WH has 8 threads, it is important to balance the biggest schema in 8 threads / tasks.

Comment: @michael-golos, thanks for sharing interesting solution. Could you provide a simple example of root and sub tasks? I have no experience in it.

Comment: If this truly accelerates a DB clone, would like to develop a stored proc that can count the objects per schema, and generate the parallel tasks based on the best distribution of work to achieve fastest execution duration.

Comment: @Aliaksandr, you are welcome, I'm glad I could help. 
How long does it take to clone after optimization?

Comment: @MichaelGolos, cloning time decreased from 15 to 5 minutes! amazing results :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try creating objects using the LIKE option? It doesn't work on databases unfortunately but does on schemas and tables etc. This creates a copy of the table with no data

So get the list of schemas and tables of your db and loop through them

```
CREATE TABLE myTable2 LIKE myTable1
```

Another option would be to use the CREATE command with a SELECT that returns no rows

```
CREATE TABLE myTable2 AS SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE 1=0
```

Not sure if any of them will be faster though

Comment: Thanks @dean-flinter. but my database also contains stages, pipes, tasks and so on. Sorry, I didn't mention it on my question. And I'm not sure that I can create a correct sequence of creating all objects based on dependensies between of snowflake objects. One example: `create table t1, then create view v1 as select * from t1, and finally create view v2 as select from v1`